# Asking for an Address using Google Actions Builder

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, actions-builder

I am attempting to build a Google Assistant app using Google Actions Builder(Not Dialogflow).

I am wanting to ask the user for an Address so I can then geocode this address. I have managed to get the users current location after asking for permission but I am unsure how I can get an address from the user should they decide not to use their current location.

I would hope that the user could be requested to Speak or type an address and I can then geocode this address. I have seen that in the legacy Actions SDK there was a place type. This does not seem to be available in Actions Builder.
I am unsure how to get and store a spoken address.

Comment: 4 years on, there is still no place type. Google Assistant is picking up local addresses from speech very badly. Hit a wall and have to live with that.